# Как понять какой элемент QListWidget был нажат?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlistwidget

Не могу понять как написать код для понимания какой элемент `QListWidget` был нажат.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не могу понять как написать код для понимания какой элемент
> QListWidget был нажат!

Для этого есть у `QListWidget` [сигнал itemClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked), что передает объект `QListWidgetItem`.

Пример использования сигнала:

```
def item_clicked(item):
    print(item)

lw = QListWidget()
lw.itemClicked.clicked(item_clicked)
```

Если `QListWidget` используется в вашем виджете, то нужно указать `self`:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.lw = QListWidget()
    self.lw.itemClicked.clicked(self.item_clicked)
    ...

def item_clicked(self, item):
    print(item)
```

---

Если нужен текущий элемент, то используйте метод [currentItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentItem)